# Selenium test saving screenshots

Tags: java, selenium, screenshot

I currently have a Selenium test that runs through a website on 11 different languages and takes screenshots of each part. The pictures themselves get saved in respective folders like this in a property file

> screenshotsEnglish.dir=/screenshots/Languages/English
>     screenshotsSwedish.dir=/screenshots/Languages/Swedish

What I want to do different is each time a test suite is run, a new base folder is created with the current date stamp followed up with the same structure as before.  How can I make this work? I can't hardcode it in the property file obviously because the date will constantly change.

To give a overall better view how it all works

```
public static Object[][] dp() {
return new Object[][]{
    {
        "https://example-URL.net/example.php?lang=EN",
        "screenshotsEnglish.dir"
    },
    {
        "https://example-URL.net/example.php?lang=SV",
        "screenshotsSwedish.dir"
    }
};
}

@Test(dataProvider = "dp")
public void t(String url, String directory) {
    driver.get(url);
    Properties settings = PropertiesLoader.fromResource("settings.properties");  
    String screenshotDir = settings.getProperty(directory);
    screenShooter = new ScreenShooter(driver, screenshotDir, "en");
    /*...*/
}
```

Tests are written in Java with TestNG

I hope I've made myself clear and as always, appreciate all help loads

Answer (score 1):

Why not like this (not tried to compile, just a quick try, so typos are possible):

```
String screenshotDir = settings.getProperty(directory); //this is what you already have
String date = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy").format(new Date()); //added: get current date
screenshotDir = screenshotDir + "/" + date; //added: create modified path
new File(screenshotDir).mkdirs(); //added: make the new directory
screenShooter = new ScreenShooter(driver, screenshotDir, "en"); //this is what you already have
```